# Number of $2$-colorings of edges of the $n$-dimensional cube?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, coloring, combinatorial-geometry, polya-counting-theory

I'm interested in counting the number of $2$-colorings of the edges of an $n$-cube up to rotations and reflections.

- For $n=1$ there are two colorings—either color the edge or don't.
- For $n=2$ there are six colorings: don't color anything, color one edge, color two opposite edges, color two adjacent edges, color all but one edge, and color everything.
- For $n=3$ there are 144 colorings.
  For general $n$ an elementary bound from Burnside's Lemma shows that the number of colorings $C(n)$ satisfies $$
    C(n) \geq \left\lceil\frac{2^{n\cdot2^{n-1}}}{2^nn!}\right\rceil
  $$ where $n2^{n-1}$ is the number of edges and $2^nn!$ is the number of symmetries, and which [grows astoundingly fast](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5BCeiling%5B2%5E%28n*2%5E%28n-1%29%29%2F%28n%21*2%5En%29%5D%2C%20%7Bn%2C1%2C6%7D%5D).

When I use Burnside's Lemma on the square or the cube, the number of colorings stabilized by some action is "intuitive", but on the hypercube and $n$-cube, this is obviously less intuitive.

However, I'm wondering if it's possible to compute $C(4)$ exactly, and find a formula $C(n)$ for all values of $n$ more generally.

Comment: You need a computer (which you obviously have), a programming tool (which you may get easily) and some knowledge about the hyperoctahedral group. This should be doable at least for small values of $n$ (e.g. $\leq 6$).

Comment: @WhatsUp, is your intuition that there's no way to compute, say $n=7$ by hand?

Comment: I haven't tried, but my intuition does say that the calculation is practically not doable by hand. Using a computer would be the best choice.

Comment: However, this doesn' mean that it's impossible to attack small cases by hand. Essentially one needs to go through the conjugacy classes of the hyperoctahedral group, and this usually involves partitions of $n$. I expect that a computer can go as far as $n = ~50$ or so in reasonable time (perhaps not getting a full answer, but the answer modulo something).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The calculation for $C(4)$ is actually less complicated than one might think if we build on the results for three dimensions.

The symmetry group of the $n$-dimensional hypercube is the [semidirect product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product) of the group $P$ of permutations of the axes (which has $n!$ elements) and the group $R$ generated by the reflections in the axes (which has $2^n$ elements). Here $R$ is the normal subgroup (whereas $P$ is not a normal subgroup of the symmetry group). Thus, we can write elements of the symmetry group as $\pi\sigma$, where $\sigma$ is a product of reflections in the axes (which I’ll denote by a string of $n$ signs indicating the orientations of the axes) and $\pi$ is a permutation of the axes.

An edge is mapped to itself (possibly inverted) by a symmetry element $g=\pi\sigma$ exactly if its direction is a fixed point of the permutation $\pi$ and its position is a fixed point of the restriction of $g$ to the remaining $n-1$ directions. (Note that the first condition ensures that the second condition is well-defined: if a direction is fixed by $\pi$, it forms a one-dimensional invariant subspace of $g$, and the remaining $n-1$ directions also form an invariant subspace, so $g$ can be restricted to them.)

This allows us to construct the edge [cycle index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_index) monomials of a symmetry element that leaves at least one axis fixed (possibly inverted) from the edge and vertex cycle index monomials of its restriction to the remaining $n-1$ directions; so the only work left to do for $n$ is for the symmetry elements whose permutations have no fixed points, and those turn out to be relatively easy to handle.

So let’s work out the cycle index monomials for the full octahedral group (in $3$ dimensions) for edges and vertices as a basis for finding the edge cycle index of the hyperoctahedral group for $n=4$. I’ll just write them out in a table without going into the details of how to obtain them since you wrote that this part seems intuitive to you. The table only includes one representative $\pi$ for each conjugacy class of $S_3$ and one representative $\sigma$ for each class of equivalent signatures (depending on $\pi$); the last column counts the symmetry elements corresponding to these classes.

\begin{array}{c|c}
\pi&\sigma&\text{edges}&\text{vertices}&\text{count}\\\hline
(1)(2)(3)&+++&a_1^{12}&a_1^8&1\\
&++-&a_1^4a_2^4&a_2^4&3\\
&+--&a_2^6&a_2^4&3\\
&---&a_2^6&a_2^4&1\\
(12)(3)&+++&a_1^2a_2^5&a_1^4a_2^2&3\\
&++-&a_1^2a_2^5&a_2^4&3\\
&+-+&a_4^3&a_4^2&6\\
&+--&a_4^3&a_4^2&6\\
&--+&a_1^2a_2^5&a_1^4a_2^2&3\\
&---&a_1^2a_2^5&a_2^4&3\\
(123)&+++&a_3^4&a_1^2a_3^2&2\\
&++-&a_6^2&a_2^1a_6^1&6\\
&+--&a_3^4&a_1^2a_3^2&6\\
&---&a_6^2&a_2^1a_6^1&2
\end{array}

Now, if the permutation of a symmetry element $g$ fixes a direction, the edges in that direction form exactly the cycles that the corresponding vertices form under the restriction of $g$ to the remaining $n-1$ directions; so one factor in the edge cycle index monomial for $n$ is the vertex cycle index monomial for $n-1$. If the fixed direction is not reflected, the edges in the remaining $n-1$ directions form the same cycles as under the restriction, but there are twice as many of them, so another factor in the edge cycle index monomial for $n$ is the square of the edge cycle index monomial for $n-1$. If the fixed direction is reflected, then cycles of even length under the restriction retain their length, but there are twice as many, so these factors get squared; whereas cycles of odd length are joined in pairs to form cycles of twice the length, so in these factors, $a_k$ is replaced by $a_{2k}$.

This allows us to obtain the following edge cycle index monomials for $n=4$, building on the table above:

\begin{array}{c|c}
\pi&\sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma_3&\sigma_4=+&\sigma_4=-&\text{count}\\\hline
(1)(2)(3)(4)&+++&a_1^{32}&a_1^8a_2^{12}&1\\
&++-&a_1^8a_2^{12}&a_2^{16}&3\\
&+--&a_2^{16}&a_2^{16}&3\\
&---&a_2^{16}&a_2^{16}&1\\
(12)(3)(4)&+++&a_1^8a_2^{12}&a_1^4a_2^{14}&6\\
&++-&a_1^4a_2^{14}&a_2^{16}&6\\
&+-+&a_4^8&a_4^8&12\\
&+--&a_4^8&a_4^8&12\\
&--+&a_1^8a_2^{12}&a_1^4a_2^{14}&6\\
&---&a_1^4a_2^{14}&a_2^{16}&6\\
(123)(4)&+++&a_1^2a_3^{10}&a_1^2a_3^2a_6^4&8\\
&++-&a_2^1a_6^5&a_2^1a_6^5&24\\
&+--&a_1^2a_3^{10}&a_1^2a_3^2a_6^4&24\\
&---&a_2^1a_6^5&a_2^1a_6^5&8
\end{array}

We’re fortunate that these are the monomials that would have been more difficult to work out in $4$ dimensions directly, whereas the remaining symmetry elements whose permutations don’t have fixed points are relatively easy to handle. If we apply such a symmetry element repeatedly, then, since all cycles in the permutation are of length at least $2$, the edges cannot return to their original position before we get back to the identity permutation. At this point, an axis is reflected exactly if the permutation cycle in which it lies contains an odd number of reflections. Again, since there are no cycles of length $1$, if some axis is reflected, then at least two axes are reflected, so again no edge can be in its original position. Thus, all edges form cycles of the same length, which is either the order of the permutation if all cycles have even numbers of reflections, or twice that if at least one cycle has an odd number of reflections.

Thus we obtain the following monomials for the derangements of the axes:

\begin{array}{c|c}
\pi&\text{$\exists$ odd}&\text{monomial}&\text{count}\\\hline
(12)(34)&\text{no}&a_2^{16}&12\\
&\text{yes}&a_4^8&36\\
(1234)&\text{no}&a_4^8&24\\
&\text{yes}&a_8^4&24
\end{array}

Now all that remains is to add up the monomials (weighted by the counts) to obtain the edge cycle index of the hyperoctahedral group for $n=4$, substitute $2$ for all variables and divide by the number $2^4\cdot4!=384$ of symmetry elements. The result is

$$
\frac{1\cdot2^{32}+16\cdot2^{20}+24\cdot2^{18}+35\cdot2^{16}+32\cdot2^{12}+164\cdot2^8+64\cdot2^6+48\cdot2^4}{384}=\boxed{11251322}\;.
$$

[Here’s Java code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/d067e29c3ebf18070b56666f40ba2494) that computes the number of equivalence classes of $2$-colorings of the edges of the $n$-dimensional hypercube under rotations and reflections (by counting the edge cycles of each symmetry element); the results up to $n=8$ are (in agreement with the above calculation):

```
1 : 2
2 : 6
3 : 144
4 : 11251322
5 : 314824456456819827136
6 : 136221825854745676520058554256163406987047485113810944
7 : 1126672129674489847701704811334332425523379727144553194843038610078657640531358451246775872508990558612282358941688264175298543616
8 : 17416266885059329153193448416467331016109182971213752603530165042718086926221183959254526030274624207791564091034795976387518055177618065547557580558563049317223935447616138542363134382681407634060633896718472077319869457188945414864160284255850798170929140736717375938929354322271320922284872609824768
```

Comment: This is an incredible answer! Thank you for this!

Answer (score 1):

I would  like to  add some auxiliary  material to  @joriki's excellent
answer.  The  key observation here  is that  we can compute  the cycle
index of  the action of the  vertex permutations on the  edges without
iterating over all  $n!$ permutations.  It is  sufficient to construct
representatives of the conjugacy classes from the cycle index $Z(S_n)$
of the  symmetric group, combine with  all possible bit flips  and let
those act  on the edges  and factor the  result into cycles.   We then
obtain for two-colorings  up to $n=9$ the sequence  (substitute two in
all variables in the cycle index)

```
2, 6, 144, 11251322, 314824456456819827136,

    136221825854745676520058554256163406987047485113810944, 11266721\
    296744898477017048113343324255233797271445531948430386100786576\

    40531358451246775872508990558612282358941688264175298543616, 174\
    162668850593291531934484164673310161091829712137526035301650427\
    180869262211839592545260302746242077915640910347959763875180551\
    776180655475575805585630493172239354476161385423631343826814076\
    340606338967184720773198694571889454148641602842558507981709291\

    40736717375938929354322271320922284872609824768, 201408138693196\
    045802848036752977184005060687650250678456207676032859963955841\
    342473532295571190513563836386169960890786266868128143883452180\
    725388624433245489779671073382998226500766903901194293671898543\
    664888193604082485646533029014852382392395665889703666411180168\
    740249005123082786262144066375934736563238179496218714717888503\
    200515641280532093461179188209394986969221439501494843089131843\
    721294579801094421049426146115437437339040034549410570659391235\
    516108535382740748592313691595052669664137206426481683808726006\
    773206206889207111402736800417347873464970875395186182424425457\
    672778183054433038403590060197086338867926867277449346734568506\
    87787652263043183549738387076300589236224
```

We get for three-colorings

```
3, 21, 12111, 4825746875682, 38491882660019692002988737797054040, 87\
    855395014850871118021858051053299243046298671949110329724919779\

    5466382109011069845048, 8723316067140811485572773377491676065629\
    735242238012145621168579760628441788336574471742772436886292305\
    595251600052101544746807508311612758243230899092573120824988147\

    658952941125332423594912528026867636629119, 36174650524419879589\
    549207335928450155146501502020361303966406610599485426864890565\
    901856334752059425036113927005002476100253349627991774648645924\
    109356882741263396035693874218736631165068932914074536307329212\
    752343892154649409634448122953527622939322595993375760007316853\
    489749600385848677015770786252465366389686754016753016152602170\
    298813279511673154477144488379230017170012315157898867724015791\
    388188289031583796141569817405401760193225723537834489330864796\

    276579279990116263783, 10431286658251081836305497766400959765498\
    084675982199503392266417824529898599330652266433338655496445367\
    609497865423633149027948859878623322094034735422962291235158227\
    096966885349321430363202338081252592834514366790183361716198072\
    069376461217393448698633527518616764184582457602257397128403242\
    719440711267984585941839659552897345866137445560317354558401405\
    727264397389704472287026787938558609939152182118708039280788427\
    940076990225007235083138607022970290005411676767786462270408012\
    468643261199704810751354236039716135434689322858062023002431864\
    459029322439881418362536298730715720051694582880810508918140773\
    992224576775854925023893846506581588062174565318579937219209218\
    706125689727008162849741226628097183102040233275966032069430394\
    829916148361692734483203842110055173557186055529941142277981713\
    874257355124877450918029476002673624525458272442454352014308842\
    647195350694355624420416227114641071642472815346093134396776394\
    108563578532920066708829408143113828102949756025217113831399006\
    264440286208679719648309927331047485794980212039405045244190783\
    8699919096867427046920827796704790431168456
```

The cycle index for $n=6$ is

$${\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{192}}{46080}}
+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{64}{a_{{2}
}}^{64}}{1536}}+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{32}{a_{{2}}}^{80}}{7680}}
\\ +{\frac {5\,{a_{{1}}}^{16}{a_{{2}}}^{88}}{768}}
+{\frac {{a_{{1}}
}^{8}{a_{{2}}}^{92}}{128}}+{\frac {229\,{a_{{2}}}^{96}}{15360}
}+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{24}{a_{{3}}}^{56}}{288}}+{\frac {{a_{{3}}
}^{64}}{72}}+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{8}{a_{{2}}}^{4}{a_{{4}}}^{44}
}{64}}
\\+1/32\,{a_{{1}}}^{4}{a_{{2}}}^{6}{a_{{4}}}^{44}+1/48\,{a
_{{1}}}^{4}{a_{{2}}}^{10}{a_{{3}}}^{20}{a_{{6}}}^{18}+{\frac {
3\,{a_{{2}}}^{8}{a_{{4}}}^{44}}{64}}+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{8}{a_{
{2}}}^{8}{a_{{3}}}^{8}{a_{{6}}}^{24}}{96}}
\\+{\frac {41\,{a_{{4}
}}^{48}}{384}}+1/48\,{a_{{1}}}^{4}{a_{{2}}}^{10}{a_{{3}}}^{4}{
a_{{6}}}^{26}+1/20\,{a_{{1}}}^{2}{a_{{5}}}^{38}+1/12\,{a_{{2}}
}^{12}{a_{{6}}}^{28}\\
+1/8\,{a_{{6}}}^{32}+1/20\,{a_{{1}}}^{2}{a
_{{5}}}^{6}{a_{{10}}}^{16}+1/8\,{a_{{8}}}^{24}+1/10\,a_{{2}}{a
_{{10}}}^{19}
\\+1/12\,{a_{{4}}}^{6}{a_{{12}}}^{14}+1/12\,{a_{{12}}}^{16}.$$

The cycle index for $n=10$ starts as follows:

$${\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{5120}}{3715891200}}+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{2048
}{a_{{2}}}^{1536}}{41287680}}+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{768}{a_{{2}}}
^{2176}}{1474560}}+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{512}{a_{{2}}}^{2304}}{
371589120}}+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{256}{a_{{2}}}^{2432}}{143360}}
\\+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{128}{a_{{2}}}^{2496}}{245760}}+{\frac {7\,{
a_{{1}}}^{64}{a_{{2}}}^{2528}}{147456}}+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{32}
{a_{{2}}}^{2544}}{24576}}+{\frac {549923\,{a_{{2}}}^{2560}}{
3715891200}}+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{896}{a_{{3}}}^{1408}}{3870720}
}\\+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{128}{a_{{3}}}^{1664}}{27648}}+{\frac {{a_
{{1}}}^{8}{a_{{3}}}^{1704}}{2592}}+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{384}{a_{
{2}}}^{192}{a_{{4}}}^{1088}}{368640}}+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{320}{
a_{{2}}}^{288}{a_{{3}}}^{576}{a_{{6}}}^{416}}{92160}}\\+{\frac {
{a_{{1}}}^{128}{a_{{2}}}^{320}{a_{{4}}}^{1088}}{12288}}+{
\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{64}{a_{{2}}}^{352}{a_{{4}}}^{1088}}{61440}}
+ \ldots$$

We get for $n=10$ the number of four-colorings

```
9486207271376467258069382762876053923320311\
    785223009505873418093008500969257320926147765116608813482605994\
    533799939668301714283097401536842598711898000709403659263993188\
    302151488236697032089736638564315679552275841400291438520396369\
    299677062241900894978610848258885210740280006366166035222799769\
    ...
    002094298108806061927699221101778932274446885312368172238250048\
    738356289717207438193189284804408313423895371241091969703565087\
    022870742286452424539334767357906029069260316865337742799740562\
    412710841763075905101778405049012389456442974281708121401602107\
    391868126920602926764589230166051991326433763396108616928307344\
    278778704027357045630921614885818871008732274675306826261076300\
    005376
```

This was the Maple code for the above computation.

```
pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local l;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;

pet_autom2cycles :=
proc(src, aut)
local numa, numsubs, k;
local marks, pos, cycs, cpos, clen;

    numsubs := [seq(src[k]=k, k=1..nops(src))];
    numa := subs(numsubs, aut);

    marks := Array([seq(true, pos=1..nops(aut))]);

    cycs := []; pos := 1;

    while pos <= nops(aut) do
        if marks[pos] then
            clen := 0; cpos := pos;

            while marks[cpos] do
                marks[cpos] := false;
                cpos := numa[cpos];
                clen := clen+1;
            od;

            cycs := [op(cycs), clen];
        fi;

        pos := pos+1;
    od;

    return mul(a[cycs[k]], k=1..nops(cycs));
end;


pet_prod2rep :=
proc(varp)
    local v, d, q, res, len, cyc, p;

    q := 1; res := [];

    for v in indets(varp) do
        d := degree(varp, v);
        len := op(1, v);

        for cyc to d do
            res :=
            [op(res),
             seq(p, p=q+1..q+len-1), q];
            q := q+len;
        od;
    od;

    res;
end;



pet_cycleind_HCE :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local idx, vert, verts, edges, bits, u, v, pos, q,
    symind, cind, term, rep, flip, edge, subl, autom;

    verts := [];
    edges := [];

    for idx from 2^n to 2*2^n-1 do
        bits := convert(idx, `base`, 2)[1..n];

        verts :=  [op(verts), bits];

        for pos to n do
            if bits[pos] = 0 then
                u := bits;
                v := [seq(bits[q], q=1..pos-1),
                      1, seq(bits[q], q=pos+1..n)];

                edges :=  [op(edges), {u,v}];
            fi;
        od;
    od;

    if n=1 then
        symind := [a[1]];
    else
        symind := pet_cycleind_symm(n);
    fi;


    cind := 0;

    for term in symind do
        rep := pet_prod2rep(term);
        for flip in verts do
            subl := [];

            for vert in verts do
                subl :=
                [op(subl),
                 vert =
                 [seq(`if`(flip[q]=1,
                       1-vert[rep[q]],
                       vert[rep[q]]),
                      q=1..n)]];
            od;

            autom := subs(subl, edges);
            cind := cind + lcoeff(term)*
            pet_autom2cycles(edges, autom);
        od;
    od;

    cind/2^n;
end;

HCE_colorings :=
proc(n, N)
option remember;
local cind, vars, v;

    cind := pet_cycleind_HCE(n);
    vars := indets(cind);

    subs([seq(v=N, v in vars)], cind);
end;
```